# "is" - operator for Type

Tags: c#, .net, types, typeof

I use the "is" operator to find a certain class:

```
for(int i=0; i<screens.Count; i++){
  if(screen is ScreenBase){
    //do something...
  }
}
```

This works fine especially as it finds any class that inherits from the ScreenBase but not the base classes from ScreenBase.

I would like to do the same when I know only the Type and don't want to instantiate the class:

```
Type screenType = GetType(line);
if (screenType is ScreenBase)
```

But this comparsion produces a warning as it will compare to the "Type" class.

The only alternative I know would be to compare with ==typeof but this would test only for the exact type and not the inherited ones.
Is there a way to get a similar behaviour like the "is" operator but for the type described by the Type-class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to know specifically if it derives from the type, use [`Type.IsSubclassOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx).  This *will not* work for interfaces.

```
Type screenType = GetType(line);
if (screenType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ScreenBase)))
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Otherwise if you want to know if the type could be assigned to a variable of a certain type, use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).  This *will* work for interfaces.

```
Type screenType = GetType(line);
if (typeof(ScreenBase).IsAssignableFrom(screenType)) // note the usage is reversed
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Do note that you don't necessarily need a type object to determine this, you can do this with an instance of the object using [`Type.IsInstanceOfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx).  It will behave more or less like `IsAssignableFrom()`.

```
if (typeof(ScreenBase).IsInstanceOfType(line)) // note the usage is reversed
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> The only alternative I know would be to compare with ==typeof but this would test only for the exact type and not the inherited ones. Is there a way to get a similar behaviour like the "is" operator but for the type described by the Type-class?

If `GetType(line)` returns a type (I'd recommend a better name for that, btw), you can use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
if (typeof(ScreenBase).IsAssignableFrom(GetType(line)))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)