# In c# how do you compare a child type with the reference of its parent?

Tags: c#

In details, I have list of multiple child classes with the reference of its parent class.
like -->

```
List<Parent> p = new List<Parent>();
Parent c1 = new Child1();
Parent c2 = new Child2();
p.Add(c1);
p.Add(c2);
```

So, when I iterate through the p list, how can I compare if the object in the list is from one specific child class.
Like I want to compare if,

```
p[i] == Child1, then do stuff//
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast - check here, you can use the `is` operator, the first example shows exactly the solution to your problem

Comment: Have you tried the answer mentioned in the below link?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16471425/8894067

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463752/is-operator-for-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `p[i]` is of a specific type by using `is`, for example:

```
if (p[i] is Child1) {
   // Do something
}
```

If you need to operate on the object, you can get a reference back to the object in addition as its type using `is` (thanks to @Jonathan Barclay), and could change your code to:

```
if (p[i] is Child1 c1) {
   // Do something with c1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pattern matching in C#7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) in switch statement for that:

```cs
switch(p[i])
{
    case Child1 child1:
        /* ... */
        Console.WriteLine(child1.propert1);
        break;
    case Child2 child1:
        /* ... */
        Console.WriteLine(child2.propert2);
        break;
    default:
        /* ... */
        Console.WriteLine("No known child!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is still a switch statement, not a switch expression. (Switch expressions were introduced in C# 8). What you've shown is *pattern matching* which was introduced in C# 7, and in particular *type patterns*. They're not specific to switch statements or expressions though - you can just use `if (p[i] is Child1 child) { ... }` - so switch at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet oops. Thank you, I've corrected that :)